# How do I override my site's link colors with classes?

Tags: html, css

I am having some trouble overriding my site's default link colors. Tried looking up similar questions but am still hitting a brick wall.

This is what I have defined as the base link colors:

```
a:link, a:visited, a:hover { color: #0279aa }
```

And this is my style override for a specific element.

```
a:link.slideshow-navigate { 
  background : #37ab4f;
  color : #fff;
}
```

I've defined my link as follows:

```
<a href="#" class="slideshow-navigate">Link name</a>
```

However, my link color still shows up as `#0279aa` instead of `#fff`. I'd like to avoid using "!important" as far as possible.

Any help will really be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh, oops! Didn't know about this. Thanks for the alert! At first I thought it was a bug of some sort. o.O

Comment: Nope, that's someone else editing your question. Edits are covered in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing), and are generally something you don't need to worry about unless they're actually bad.

Comment: Noted, sorry about that! (:

Comment: It's alright, no need to apologize! BTW, I just followed you on Twitter - several people I know follow you too and I myself am a Singaporean as well :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be like

```
a.slideshow-navigate{
    background : #37ab4f;
    color : #fff;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HN37L/1/)**

Comment: @Mr_Green: How would that make it any different from the question code, then?

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't get you. But now I referred that `a` and `a:link` are same. I am still getting doubt why that can't be done.

Comment: @Mr_Green: `a` and `a:link` are not the same. `a.slideshow-navigate:link` and the question's `a:link.slideshow-navigate` on the other hand are the same, but won't apply to `:visited` or `:hover`. The answer here removes the pseudo-class altogether so it will apply to any state.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Strangely, I was using a.slideshow-navigate previously which didn't work either - but after seeing this response and the no. of upvotes I deduced I must have been doing something else wrongly. I later realized that the stylesheet which was defining 'a.slideshow-navigate' was included BEFORE the stylesheet defining my base link colors. I've fixed that and now it works. (:

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
a.slideshow-navigate
    {
        color:#fff;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

you can do this with

```
a:link:not[href^="http"]{

background : #37ab4f;
  color : #fff;
}
```

dont need to add a class in every link

this will style all link that are internal and avoid external links 
that starts from `http`.

Comment: its not possible to every time add a class in a link its easy